# Return NULL as Zero from my SQL Pivot query

Tags: sql-server, null, pivot

I'm using SQL Server 2014 and I have a Pivot Query that runs on my database and works fine. My problem is that the certain fields have NULL in them. I want the NULLS to be replaced by a Zero.

My query stands as follows:

```
(SELECT [PROPERTYCODE],
        [MARKET FINAL],
        [MARCH 2015],
        [APRIL 2015],
        [MAY 2015]          

FROM (SELECT [PropertyCode],
         [MTH],
         [Room Nights],
         [Market FINAL]

   FROM HOLDINGS2

)m

PIVOT (Sum([ROOM NIGHTS])
     FOR [MTH] IN ([MARCH 2015],
                   [APRIL 2015],
                   [MAY 2015]                      
                    )) AS PVTTABLE)
 ORDER BY [PropertyCode],[Market FINAL]
```

The output looks like this:

```
PropertyCode   MarketFinal  March 2015  April 2015    May 2015 

    A            UK           245          NULL          320
```

I need the NULLS to be zeroes.

I've tried this on the Pivot statement:

```
PIVOT (Sum(NULLIF[ROOM NIGHTS],0))
```

But it doesn't work. I also tried the NULLIF in the first select statement of my query next to [MARCH 2015], [APRIL 2015] AND [MAY 2015] but it still does not work!

Comment: You have to replace the `null` in the final select list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [NULLIF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177562.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) function will return 0 if both expressions are equal, so it will replace a 0 by a null in your example.

Have a look at the [ISNULL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) function

```
(SELECT [PROPERTYCODE],
    [MARKET FINAL],
    [MARCH 2015],
    [APRIL 2015],
    [MAY 2015]          

FROM (SELECT [PropertyCode],
     [MTH],
     isnull([Room Nights] , 0),
     [Market FINAL]

FROM HOLDINGS2

)m

PIVOT (Sum([ROOM NIGHTS])
 FOR [MTH] IN ([MARCH 2015],
               [APRIL 2015],
               [MAY 2015]                      
                )) AS PVTTABLE)
 ORDER BY [PropertyCode],[Market FINAL]
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Indeed, the ISNULL function worked perfectly.

Comment: @TomV Not my DV but are you certain that placing the `IsNull` function inside the pivot aggregate works?  When I test it, this syntax throws an error. Typically the pivot syntax does not allow a function inside of that aggregate.

Comment: @TomV I placed the ISNULL next to [March 2015], [April 2015], etc.. and not inside the pivot syntax.

Comment: I couldn't test the syntax indeed @user3115933 i've edited it, is it now correct?